# java.awt.image.DataBufferInt cannot be cast to java.awt.image.DataBufferByte

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

```
private static byte[] get_byte_data(BufferedImage image)
{
    //WritableRaster raster   = image.getRaster();
    DataBufferByte buffer = (DataBufferByte)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
    return buffer.getData();
}
```

I get the stated class cast exception while executing the above piece of code. I need the byte[] array to be returned. i.e the bytes of the bufferedimage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The raster data is not necessarily bytes.

`if (image.getRaster().getDataTypeSize() == 1)`, then you can use `getElem(int bank, int i)` for all banks and all elements, and store the results in the desired array. I don't see anything more direct.

Comment: @Alex  What do you mean not necessarily bytes? The `image` here is a BufferedImage. So why can't raster data be bytes?

Comment: look at the API : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/DataBuffer.html
it can be anything from a byte to a double